# Direct full screen of html5 video when starting to play in UIWebview

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, fullscreen

We serve 3rd party videos in a iOS native app through UIWebviews.

On the iPhone when playing a video it directly switches to a fullscreen video view. On the iPad the video plays inline. This is expected according to Apple documentation.

This is because the value:

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback
```

is by default set to NO on iPhone and YES to iPad.

I would like to see the same behaviour on playback on the iPhone as on the iPad. So that is plays the video directly fullscreen. Setting `webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to NO does not do the trick.

Comment: Hey do u have find the solution of this problem to play the youtube video on iPad in full screen similar to iPhone? if yes, please provide the solution.

Comment: No sorry I did not manage to make this work. Seems it is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the conclusion here is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML5 source code add playsinline like in this example:
        video controls="controls" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline">

In your app, in the method you are calling to setup webview add
       webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;

Comment: Thanks! But this results in the complete opposite I want to accomplish. We want the video never to play in line and start the full screen view directly on playback.